# Asynchronously load images from document directory into UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to load images from document directory into `UICollectionView`. It works: smooth, fast....(lol). But I get one issue: when I call `[collectionView reloadData]`, images flicker(once time). Here is my code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView_ cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = NSStringFromClass([AFMyRecentCollectionViewCell class]);
    AFMyRecentCollectionViewCell *cell = (AFMyRecentCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView_ dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    AFMyRecentObject *recent = [[AFRecentManager sharedInstance].arrayRecent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *image;
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *filePath = [self databasePathWithPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", recent.id_film]];
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath] == YES) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (image) {
                cell.imageView.image = image;
            } else {
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loadding.png"];
            }
        });
    });

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)databasePathWithPathComponent:(NSString*)pathComponent {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex: 0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponent];
    return path;
}
```

Comment: By the way, you technically should be making sure that the `cell` hasn't be reused for another `NSIndexPath` by the time the `UIImage` has been instantiated. Most likely, because you're retrieving from local storage, that's unlikely to be an issue, but if you were to be initiating any network requests, that suddenly becomes a very real issue when scrolling quickly while on cellular networks. So be very careful using the above pattern unless you are confident that the cell cannot be reused while the asynchronous update is in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced same issue of flickring the images & solved it using below approach.

Apply same lazy loading concept. Like create one dictionary object to store all images before displaying, Before getting the image from the document directory check wether that images is there in the dictionary if it's there then then user that image to display it.

If image is not there in the dictionary then do database operation.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: If you do this technique, I'd recommend (a) `NSCache` rather than dictionary; and (b) make sure you purge this data structure upon receiving memory warning. Also note that this doesn't get to the root of the issue, namely the failure to initialize the `image` property before initiating the asynchronous call.

Comment: @Rob: I haven't used NSCache yet. I will try to use it. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

You have to place and default/placeholder image to prevent that..

```
    // this prevents the flicker/blinks
    cell.imageView.image = nil; // if you dont have any image as placeholder

    //since you have 
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loadding.png"]; // this i assume your placeholder image?

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        //your codes..
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // your codes..
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're initiating the asynchronous update of the image view, but if the cell is reused, you're going to see the old image there. So, before you `dispatch_async` the process to retrieve the image, make sure you set `cell.imageView.image` to `nil` first. So make sure you never see the prior image in the cell before initiating the asynchronous retrieval of the correct image.